# Subclass models in subfolders are not autoloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two levels of inheritance with some of my models: (this is all in `/app/models`)

```
A.rb
/A/B1.rb
/A/B1/C1.rb
/A/B1/C2.rb
/A/B1/C3.rb
/A/B2.rb
/A/B2/C1.rb
/A/B2/C2.rb
/A/B2/C3.rb
...
```

A.rb is a simple:

```
class A
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    puts "New subclass: #{subclass}"
  end

  # some methods
end
```

B1.rb is:

```
class A::B1 < A
  # some methods
end
```

C1.rb is:

```
class A::B1::C1 < A::B1
  # some methods
end
```

You can interpolate what the rest of the models look like.

When I load `rails console`, I see this:

```
New subclass: A::B1
New subclass: A::B1::C1
New subclass: A::B2
```

Notice that **A::B1::C2, A::B1::C3, and none of the A::B2 subclasses are inherited**! Why is that?

It gets even weirder. In `rails console`, I can then do this:

```
irb(main)> A::B1::C2
New subclass: A::B1::C2
A::B1::C2 < A::B1
irb(main)> A::B2::C1
New subclass: A::B2::C1
A::B2::C1 < A::B2
```

So I can type all the subclasses that weren't inherited, and then suddenly it fires the `puts` message. I think this proves the issue is with the autoloader, rather than my code.

This is happening in my **development environment** with Ruby 1.9. and Rails 3.2.

Here are my `config.autoload_paths` statements:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your autoload config is in `config/application.rb` and might look like this: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib...` Is it overwriting the autoload paths or appending to them? You should load Rails context with `rails console`. Rails is what reads `application.rb`. `irb` is just for plain Ruby.

Comment: Hey @Chloe - this is all I have: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` and `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`

Comment: You're right - I have been using `rails c`. I'll update my question. Thx!

Comment: Also try `class.parent` and `class.superclass` and see what it prints. `A::B1::C1.parent` and `A::B1::C1.superclass`.

Comment: `A::B1::C1.parent` and `A::B1::C1.superclass` both return `A::B1 < A`. The classes that weren't autoloaded return the same thing.

Comment: What happens if you define the classes with explicit modules instead of the implicit modules? `module A; module B1; class C1 < A::B1; end; end; end;`

Comment: `app/models/A/B1/C1.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': A is not a module (TypeError)`. If I change A to a module, then I get inheritance errors: `wrong argument type Module (expected Class) (TypeError)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56250/discussion-between-simon-d-and-chloe).

Comment: Aren't you confusing autoloading with eager loading?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I don't believe I am. This is happening to me in my development environment, where as I understand it, everything is autoloaded. In production, everything is eager loaded and I wouldn't expect to have this problem. That make sense?

Comment: @simon.d: is this happening to you in production?

Comment: When I type `RAILS_ENV=production rails console`, all the subclasses load! So the problem is definitely specific to `RAILS_ENV=development`

Comment: @simon.d: I'd guess that you never reference those classes anywhere. So they don't get autoloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include the various models in your `config.autoload_paths` option:

```
#config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

This makes use of [globbing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) - basically adding any files within a particular directory to your path. We use the above code for single-level directories (`app/models/directory/1.rb`); if you wanted to use multiple levels, you'll have to indicate them like this:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{*}', '{**}')]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. `puts config.autoload_paths` does print all the C1.rb, C2.rb, etc. files, so I can tell I have my paths right. However the same set of classes print `New subclass` (exact same behavior as before).

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had a better answer but to Sergio's point, my subclasses are never directly mentioned so they aren't autoloaded.

I literally had to just write them out at the top of my class file:

B1.rb:

```
class A1::B1

  A1::B1::C1 # simply mentioning the class autoloads it
  A1::B2::C2
  ...

  def foo
    ...
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late to help you, but I ran into the same issue, so hopefully this answer will help others.

If you are using the `Spring` gem, your application is actually running in the background. So simply restarting won't re-run the initializers, and won't add those directories to your autoload path.

You want to run `bin/spring stop` so that when you restart your app the initializers are run.